# Troubles with os.system('exit')

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working in a game,I'm coding in Python and I have ubuntu/linux.
I'm having a problem with a os.system('clear') it doesn't work well.
Here is the code:

```
    elif acc == 'dinero':
        print('Tienes ' + str(dinero) + '$')
    elif acc == 'salir':
        os.system('exit')
```

Here is some part of the code, the problem is at the second elif, if I input "salir" it just freeze and stays running. I've another os.sytem('exit') in the code but it works well and I don't know how to solve it, any idea? All the others inputs work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you type `exit` in the terminal (what `os.system` essentially does), you exit the entire session, not just your program. Since you just want to exit your program, do the following:

```
import sys
# ...
elif acc == "salir":
    sys.exit(0)
```

A more in-depth explanation of the difference between the two (please edit if you can make this more correct or understandable).

When you run a program from a shell on Linux/Mac/Windows, there are two programs running, the shell and your own program.  Your program is running as a "child process" of the shell. This means the shell "owns" it. If your program exits, the shell is left still running.

Imagine walking your dog and your dog dies. you can still finish your walk or do whatever. That's what `sys.exit(0)` does. It's your dog killing itself so you can continue walking.

However, `os.system("exit")` is like your dog taking you over and making you kill yourself, which kills both you and your dog. He can't survive without you and other things you're doing at the same time will also die because they can't survive without you either.

This is a simplified answer, but that's essentially what's happening.

Comment: Works well,  but why in one case works and in the other one doesn't work?

Comment: Now I understood it, thanks :) And what an example xD